# Can I replace treatment numbers in a column with treatment labels, in Excel?

Tags: excel

In one column only of my data, I would like to transform my numeric variables (0,1,2) to named variables (text, text + picture, text + video). I have never coded in excel before so am not sure where to start or how to include my data here.

Thank you so much!

Below is a screenshot of some of my data. I do need help, please let me know how to upload my data. Please do not close this answer without letting me know specifically how I can improve my answer, I'm new at this and am eager to learn. :)

[image]

---

Comment: What should the expected output be?

Comment: As in any other programming language, you'll have to create a list of expected values (0,1,2) and the translated values (text, ...). This can be done in Excel without programming (VBA), just using formulas. Read up on `VLOOKUP`. If you want to code the solution in VBA, it's the same logic as R. Just loop over your range of values (everything in your column) and translate the values you find into the translated value.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I'd like to replace the 0,1,2's with  'text', 'text + photo', and 'text + video' in the corresponding cells. Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Yes - just use Find/Replace. You can use the macro recorder to get you started.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks! That's very helpful. How do I insert the code? Do you have sample code that may work? Thank you so much.

Comment: Great, so Find/Replace won't replace all the 1's 2's and 0's in the sheet right? Just the column?

Comment: Not if you select just that column.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that right now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, that worked!!